# How to position your labels in stacked bar graph plot in ggplot where the y axis is "count"?

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, bar-chart, label

## plotting the ggplot with x axis as names(categorical) and y axis came default as count

```
gnew = ggplot(data= got, aes(x= got$attacker_king, fill= got$attacker_outcome))+
    geom_bar() +
    geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label =..count..), vjust = -.5)+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,20)) # plotting the stacked ggplot #this works
```

## Trying to position the labels according to the position of the fills

```
got = ddply(got, .(got$attacker_king), 
    transform, pos = cumsum(..count..)- (0.5 *..count..)) # positioning labels shows error

#This shows error as "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '..count..' not found"

Please help!
```

## this is what i have with ggplot

(they are not in their right positions. positions need to be swapped and centered)
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `position=position_stack(vjust=0.5)` in the `geom_text()` call.

An example using the `iris` dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data= iris, aes(x= Sepal.Width, fill= Species))+
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label =..count..), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,20))
```

[image]

**EDIT** as per request of how to calculate percentages.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

summary<-as.data.frame(iris %>%
group_by(Species,Sepal.Width) %>%
  tally  %>%
  group_by(Sepal.Width) %>%
  mutate(pct=(100*n)/sum(n)))


ggplot(data= summary, aes(x= Sepal.Width, y=n,fill= Species))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label =round(pct,2)), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),size=3)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,20))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. If it's not too much trouble, can you tell how to calculate percentage of these values given the axes are the same??

Comment: but how come the total percentage of one bar doesn't add upto 100%? Is it possible to divide the 100% and distribute to each section of the bar? For eg. one bar = 70%,30% and another one 17% and 83%

Comment: @EdwinVarghese I wasn't quite sure what you wanted. See the update, just needed to change the `group_by()` variable.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a ton J.Con !!

Comment: I did upvote. It is'nt publicly shown because I need 7 repuations more to show my upvote. I'm new here. Thanks again

Comment: @EdwinVarghese ah, no worries. Good luck